# best way to find if an array is a permutation

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

A non-empty array `A` consisting of `N` integers is given.

A permutation is a sequence containing each element from 1 to `N`  exactly once each.
For example, `[4,2,1,3]`
is a permutation, but `[4,1,3]` 
is not a permutation, because value `2` is missing.

The goal is to check whether the input array `A` is a permutation.

**constraints**

- N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
- Each element of `A` is an integer within the range [1..1,000,000,000].

My code:

```
# 1 = permutation 0 = not a permutation
def solution(A):
    total = sum(A)

    formula_total = (len(A)*(len(A)+1))/(2)

    if total == formula_total:

        return 1

    return 0
```

my solution is failing on Antisum (I don't know what that is )

Comment: Why do you think that a condition on `total` is necessary and sufficient for something to be a permutation? You lose all sorts of information when you form a sum. `1+3 = 2+2`, so your idea seems to be a non-starter. Why not just sort?

Comment: Note that if any `A[i]` is greater than `N`, then you can immediately return 0. All you need is an array of size `N`. Initialize every entry with 0. Scan the input array and increment the `array[A[i]]`. If `array[A[i]]` is 2, immediately return 0.

Comment: @JohnColeman I thought that `total` will be different than sum of first N integer `formula_total` but clearly that is not the case.

Comment: @HarpreetSingh It says right there in the description of the test what "antiSum" is: total sum is correct, but it is not a permutation, N <= 10. This is exactly made for your kind of algorithm, which is wrong because `[2, 2, 2]` will return true with your code.

Comment: @ChatterOne Thanks for the explanation.  Checking `len(set(A)) == len(A)` condition solves the issue of "antiSum" in my code.

Answer (score 7):

You can then check if the minimum value of the list is 1 and if the maximum value is equal to the length of the list. You can then convert the list to a set to check if the length is equal, and if so, all items in the list are unique and therefore the list is what you consider a permutation:

```
def solution(A):
    return min(A) == 1 and max(A) == len(A) == len(set(A))
```

so that:

```
print(solution([4,2,1,3]))
print(solution([4,1,3]))
print(solution([4,2,1,4]))
print(solution([4,2,5,3]))
```

outputs:

```
True
False
False
False
```

If you want `1` and `0` as the returning value you can pass the Boolean value to the `int()` constructor instead:

```
def solution(A):
    return int(min(A) == 1 and max(A) == len(A) == len(set(A)))
```

Comment: I believe that this fails if given an internally damaged array, such as `[1, 2, 2, 4]`.  We're not guaranteed that the input values are already unique.

Comment: No this won't fail for your given scenario because it won't pass the `len(set(A)) == len(A)` test, which is exactly there to make sure that the input values are unique.

Comment: OOPS!  I scanned right past the `set` call.  Thanks.

Comment: thanks I add `if len(set(A)) != len(A): return 0 ` in my and my function is running on all test cases.

Comment: @HarpreetSingh I've updated my answer with a solution to return `1` and `0` instead if that's what you're looking for. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)

Answer (score 5):

This is simply a version of the anagram problem.  Sort the input array.  Compare it for equality against an array of elements 1 through N.  Return the Boolean result of that comparison.

If you need a linear solution, then declare `seen`, a Boolean array of size N.  Iterate through the input array.  Count the elements as you process them.

For each element A

- if A not in range 1-N return failure
- if `seen[A]` return failure
- `seen[A]` = True

At the end, return `count == N`.  In other words, if `count == N`, we've found one of each integer; return True.  Otherwise, return False (count would be less than `N` in that case).

Answer (score 1):

```
def getMax(A):
    max_ele = 0
    for each_integer in A:
        max_ele = max(max_ele,each_integer)
    return max_ele

def restoreArray(A):
    for idx, val in enumerate(A):
        A[idx] = abs(A[idx])

def solution(A):
    max_ele = getMax(A)
    if len(A) != max_ele:
        return False
    for idx, val in enumerate(A):
        if A[abs(A[idx]) - 1] < 0:
            # restore the array back   
            restoreArray(A)
            return False
        else:
            A[abs(A[idx]) - 1] = -A[abs(A[idx]) - 1]

    # restore the array back   
    restoreArray(A)
    return True


print(solution([4,2,1,3]))
print(solution([4,1,3]))
print(solution([4,2,1,4]))
print(solution([4,2,5,3]))
print(solution([1,2,3,4]))
print(solution([1,2,3,4,6,7,2]))
print(solution([9,2,3,4,6,7,5,8,1]))
print(solution([9,2,3,4,6,7,5,8,1,10,6]))
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
False
False
True
False
True
False
```

**Algorithm:**

- We can take advantage of the constraint that all the elements are positive.
- Hence, we loop over the array and mark indexes as visited by making the integer at a particular index negative.
- Now, if we come across an index which points to another index that is already negative, we return `False`.
- If we never come across such situation, it surely is a permutation and we return `True`.
- We do restore the array back so that we don't modify it in place.
- Time Complexity: **O(n)**, Space Complexity: **O(1)**.
- You can make this solution more pythonic(since I ain't a python enthusiast) which I leave as an exercise to you.

Comment: Conceptually I like this (+1) but I suspect that the `set()` -based solution will be more efficient in CPython since a function written in C does the heavy lifting rather than the interpreter running a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The fasted solution here is with

```py
import numpy as np

# create integer array `data`

seen = np.zeros(len(data), dtype=bool)
seen[data] = True
is_permutation = np.all(seen)
```

[as suggested by @Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53641804/353337). The sort-and-compare-with-arange suggestion is about 20 times slower.

[image]

---

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot


def setup(n):
    return np.random.permutation(np.arange(n))


def sort(data):
    return np.sort(data) == np.arange(len(data))


def seen(data):
    seen = np.zeros(len(data), dtype=bool)
    seen[data] = True
    return np.all(seen)


def min_max_set(data):
    return min(data) == 0 and max(data) + 1 == len(data) == len(set(data))


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[sort, seen, min_max_set],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(23)],
    xlabel="len(array)",
)
b.save("out.png")
b.show()
```